# Is there a security risk using bluetooth computer speakers?

Tags: bluetooth

I need to get new computer speakers/subwoofer and bluetooth speakers sound great since they would decrease the amount of wires around my desk. Is there a security risk having bluetooth enabled all the time or anytime I would use speakers? I'll stick with wires if there's any unnecessary risk.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, enabling Bluetooth will increase your attack surface.  If you do not have Bluetooth enabled, you close a whole series of possible attacks.  There was [a series of vulnerabilities disclosed recently](https://www.armis.com/blueborne/) which highlight the risk of having Bluetooth enabled.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll stick with the wired speakers to be safe.

Comment: What if one connects an audio player to the computer with a hardline, and then connects the audio player to speakers with Bluetooth?

Comment: That's a great idea @Accumulation. That is what I would call "air-gapped" because the audio out is a one-way signal. It's not "connected" in the sense that an attack could come upstream at that point.